# what should be the shape of target data in LSTM for predicting number in the sequence

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am working with keras functional API on LSTM. where a have given a input sequence of 3 features and predicting the next value in it. for eg
input

```
[10, 20, 30]
```

target

```
[40]
```

given below is input data.

```
[[[10, 20, 30],
  [20, 30, 40],
  [30, 40, 50],
  [40, 50, 60],
  [50, 60, 70],
  [60, 70, 80],
  [70, 80, 90]]]
```

And target data.

```
[ 40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100]
```

here is my code. for creating input array and target array

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from numpy import array
def own_split_sequence():
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(10,100,10):
        if i+30 > 100:
            break
        seq_x = [i, i+10, i+20]
        seq_y = i+30
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
```

reshape the input according to (samples, timesteps, features)

```
x1 = X.reshape((1,7,3))
```

model code.

```
visible = Input(shape=(7,3))
hidden1 = LSTM(10)(visible)
output = Dense(1,activation='relu')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible,outputs=output)
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

```
model.fit(x1, y, epochs=150, verbose=2)
```

and here in fit method it is giving an error

```
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 1 input samples and 7 target samples.
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is mostly to do with the input and target shapes. You are right in quoting that the input has to be reshaped to (samples, timesteps, features). But the code below doesn't reflect that. You have 7 samples, each having 3 timesteps, with one feature for a timestep.

```
    x1 = X.reshape((7,3,1))
```

Also the target has to be reshaped to match the same pattern. Timestep dimension will be squeezed in the target.

```
    y = y.reshape((7,1))
```

Comment: if i did this it does not gives correct output for [20,30,40] as [50]. and i think timsteps are 7 features are 3. tell me how will i get the correct output.

Comment: U mean the model doesn't give correct output, or you are not able to run fit method at all?

Comment: That is mostly to do with the insufficient training data. What is it outputting though? How far off are the results. Since your training data here contains only 7 samples, 1 epoch would mean 1 training step and considering the adam's default learning rate it might not have learnt much within 150 steps.

Answer (score 0):

```
x1 = X.reshape((7,3,1))
visible = Input(shape=(3,1))
hidden1 = LSTM(10,activation='relu')(visible)
output = Dense(1,activation='relu')(hidden1)
model = Model(inputs=visible,outputs=output)
```

this worked for me